# How can I test app sandboxing without a Mac Developer Program account

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

I can develop for iOS using the Simulator without an iOS Developer Program account (I just can't run on a device.) Is there an equivalent way of working for Mac Developer Program stuff? I want to test some of my utility apps for sandboxing compatibility (and therefore App Store distribution) prior to signing up for a paid account. If my apps don't work or aren't at least easily fixable, it's not worth the $99.

Are there project settings I can enable which enforce sandboxing? I expect that code signing will not work.

Comment: Review the [migration guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/MigratingALegacyApp/MigratingAnAppToASandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH6-SW1) to see if your app can make the necessary adjustments first.

Comment: @Nick I've previously looked at that. I'm at the point where I really need to just try it. I think it'll work but that's only because I can't find explicit references to the things I'm doing being prohibited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the [App Sandbox Design Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxQuickStart/AppSandboxQuickStart.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH2-SW3), which has sections about creating code signing certificates for testing your apps. You can do it entirely in Keychain Access without requiring a paid Apple ID.

Comment: Just saw your glider avatar. I have a GoL-powered app on sale now; small world.

Comment: this link seems outdated - there's no section for creating code signing certificates for testing.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like that info was moved or deleted. Upvoted your answer; maybe @TimKemp wants to change the accepted answer?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a self-signed certificate for code signing:

1. Open Keychain Access.
2. Choose Keychain Access > Certificate Assistant > Create Certificate ...
3. Enter a name
4. Set 'Certificate Type' to 'Code Signing'

Then, in Xcode > Target > Build Settings > Code Signing, you should see your new certificate show up in the drop down next to Code Signing Identity.